# How to handle exception after maximum retry exceeded in celery

Tags: python, celery

I have a following program which raise exception if number is odd and return value if it is even. Now if maximum retry is exceeded, then its raise the previous occured exception. What I want to do is that after maximum retry exceeded, I would like to log this exception. I'm little bit confused how to acheived this.
Here is the following code:

```
import random

from celery import Celery

app = Celery('add', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')

@app.task(bind=True)
def add(self, x, y):
    # Get a random number between 1 and 10
    num = random.randint(1, 10)
    print num # To help properly understand output
    try:
        # If number is odd, fail the task
        if num % 2:
            raise Exception()
        # If number is even, succeed the task
        else:
            return x + y
    except Exception as e:
        self.retry(countdown=2, exc=e, max_retries=1)
```

The exception is

```
[2015-07-31 17:47:33,681: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: add.add[64e43f81-0f80-49ac-a068-4c84c689ea16]
[2015-07-31 17:47:33,681: WARNING/Worker-2] 7
[2015-07-31 17:47:33,703: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: add.add[64e43f81-0f80-49ac-a068-4c84c689ea16] eta:[2015-07-31 12:17:35.692557+00:00]
[2015-07-31 17:47:33,704: INFO/MainProcess] Task add.add[64e43f81-0f80-49ac-a068-4c84c689ea16] retry: Retry in 2s: Exception()
[2015-07-31 17:47:36,890: WARNING/Worker-4] 3
[2015-07-31 17:47:36,894: ERROR/MainProcess] Task add.add[64e43f81-0f80-49ac-a068-4c84c689ea16] raised unexpected: Exception()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/akshar/.virtualenvs/hack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
  ...
  File "/Users/akshar/Play/Python/hack/add.py", line 15, in add
    raise Exception()
Exception
```

Instead of this raise Exception(), I want to log it anyhow. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can add an if check before the odd-even and print or save log.

```
import random

from celery import Celery

app = Celery('add', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')

@app.task(bind=True)
def add(self, x, y):
# Get a random number between 1 and 10
num = random.randint(1, 10)
print num # To help properly understand output
try:
    if max_retries!=1:# count of max_retry

        # If number is odd, fail the task
        if num % 2:
            raise Exception()
        # If number is even, succeed the task
        else:
            return x + y
    else:
        print "log the result"
except Exception as e:
    self.retry(countdown=2, exc=e, max_retries=1)
```

You can also add a finally blok at the end of try, except so in each case it will run and you can keep all log in there.

Comment: Please post a valid code snippet. Your code will not run.